# OSX Mavericks doesn't reboot/shutdown/logout from menubar

Tags: macos, shutdown, reboot, user-account

`sudo reboot` or `sudo halt` works when executed from terminal. But, Apple Logo -> Shutdown/Restart/Log Out User doesn't work. Strangely, Apple Logo -> Sleep works.

I've executed bunch of defaults write and setting changes in the Terminal recently, and I'm not sure which one triggered this problem. Unfortunately, I didn't take any snapshots or backed up original state.

Which files should I look into regarding the enable/disable of reboot/shutdown/logout from menubar?

How do I fix this, or where do I start looking?

Comment: Did you change **anything** via Terminal?

Comment: Yes. I've executed bunch of `defaults write` and setting changes, and I'm not sure which one triggered this problem. Unfortunately, I didn't take any snapshots or backed up original state. Which files should I look into regarding the enable/disable of reboot/shutdown/logout from menubar?

Comment: You could install Mavericks again from the AppStore it will only update the system files and not remove your personal data.

Comment: Would suggest that you keep record of any of those settings changes that you do together with the references to sites/documents that suggested them.  A lot of these are relatively simple stuff, but there can be unintended consequences

Answer (score 1):

Since no one knows what you did in Terminal in the past your best option is:

Reinstall Mavericks from AppleStore.

It will not temper with you personal data.

It will however rest any changes you made to the system and preferences.

see [this for instructions how to](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH13871).